# Python OOP - using instance variable

Tags: python, oop, variables, instance

I'm learning Python right now and have some trouble understanding this piece of code(https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html):

```
class Dog:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.tricks = []    # creates a new empty list for each dog

    def add_trick(self, trick):
        self.tricks.append(trick)
```

My question is why don't we declare **tricks** variable inside the **def **init**()**:

Why is it not correct ?

```
class Dog:

    def __init__(self, name, tricks):
        self.name = name
        self.tricks = []
```

Thank you.

Comment: You don't have to do that in Java either. You are initializing an empty array in the `__init__` the same way you would initialize an empty `ArrayList` in Java using a constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Dog:

    def __init__(self, name, tricks):
        self.name = name
        self.tricks = []
```

In Python, the parameters passed to the **init** function are the initialization parameters, i.e., the parameters used to instantiate the object itself. In the first code snippet of your question, you create a `Dog` object which knows no tricks (the inner variable `tricks` is set to `[]`). In the former, you pass some tricks your dog, and you should save it inside the class:

```
class Dog:

    def __init__(self, name, tricks):
        self.name = name
        self.tricks = tricks
```

Long story short:

The first code snippet is used to create a `Dog` who knows no tricks, but you can add some tricks later.

The second one is used to create a `Dog` with pre-learnt tricks.